# HP Product Warranty API

Tags: api

Has anyone had any experience with this: https://developers.hp.com/css/api/product-warranty-api#!/queries/post_queries

I can't find much else on it. I tried plugging their Curl example in, but it throws an EoF error. It's also confusing because the URL says "**test**.css.api.hp.com". Is that the one to use? It also lists the example API key twice. Is one of them supposed to be the consumer key, and the other consumer secret?

My goal is obviously to get warranty information programmatically. I want to be able to send out alerts when laptops are expiring, as well as log the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gone through the warranty API. I used the API key provided in the test.css test URL. It looks like we need to invoke the following URL
https://test.css.api.hp.com/productWarranty/queries?apikey=jVA1nQmdGot1U7el0LRdEg9mXsuMpF9z and post the following content to it.

```
[
  {
    "sn": "CN71150F4Z",
    "pn": "590639-371"
  },
  {
    "sn": "CN71150F5N",
    "pn": "590639-371"
  },

  {
    "sn": "CN71150F54",
    "pn": "590639-371"
  },

  {
    "sn": "CN71150F5D",
    "pn": "590639-371"
  },

  {
    "sn": "CN711506FS",
    "pn": "5603588-B21
  }
]
```

After posting the data, I received the following response.

> [     {       "sn": "CN71150F4Z",         "pn": "590639-371",         "product": null,
>         "serviceType": null,        "type": "Base Warranty",        "status":
>   "Expired",        "startDate": "2011-04-21T00:00:00Z",        "endDate":
>   "2011-04-21T00:00:00Z",       "serviceLevel": null    },  {       "sn":
>   "CN71150F5N",         "pn": "590639-371",         "product": null,
>         "serviceType": null,        "type": "Base Warranty",        "status":
>   "Expired",        "startDate": "2011-04-21T00:00:00Z",        "endDate":
>   "2011-04-21T00:00:00Z",       "serviceLevel": null    },  {       "sn":
>   "CN71150F54",         "pn": "590639-371",         "product": null,
>         "serviceType": null,        "type": "Base Warranty",        "status":
>   "Expired",        "startDate": "2011-04-21T00:00:00Z",        "endDate":
>   "2011-04-21T00:00:00Z",       "serviceLevel": null    },  {       "sn":
>   "CN71150F5D",         "pn": "590639-371",         "product": null,
>         "serviceType": null,        "type": "Base Warranty",        "status":
>   "Expired",        "startDate": "2011-04-21T00:00:00Z",        "endDate":
>   "2011-04-21T00:00:00Z",       "serviceLevel": null    },  {       "sn":
>   "CN711506FS",         "pn": null,         "product": null,        "serviceType": null,
>         "type": "Base Warranty",        "status": "Expired",        "startDate":
>   "2011-04-18T00:00:00Z",       "endDate": "2011-04-18T00:00:00Z",
>         "serviceLevel": null    } ]

I'm wondering how do we get a personal API key. In case of Dell's API they have provided a clear document to get an API key and use it. Here when we click on getting an personal API key nothing works.

Comment: Correct, using the API key through their generator results in a 401 error. Only their key works. I've spent hours on the phone trying to track down who is responsible for this service, and have gotten no where. I was able to get it working through your suggestions.

Comment: I will try to gather as much information as I can to get our own personal api key. Meanwhile if you come across any contact info related to this, please let me know. I will also update here if I get any contact.

Comment: I'm also noticing it's only returning base warranty, and not extended or additional warranties. These warranties show up on HP's site.

Comment: @TylerMontney, HP has now enabled the product warranty api public. We can get our own key by registering here. https://developers.hp.com/css.

Comment: For anyone using the above and getting `access denied` you need to visit the non-member URL at https://developers.hp.com/css-enroll

Answer (score 1):

The current answer is no longer applicable. The warranty API for HP products is now available (with signup) at https://developers.hp.com/css/api/product-warranty-api-0. You can now get your own API key and secret, and the old one is not intended to be shared or used anymore. It will not work.